# DS4208 Symbol scanner ADF removing data from string

Tags: barcode-scanner, symbols

I need to write a rule to remove data from the string below. With 123scan. 
I have tried several rule sets that don't work.

DATA STRING:

```
<Enter> 
[).06<GS>**18vlelme**]1Pkrc11866/2<GS>21pr1g<GS>12d20151127<GS>q1<GS>1vcf8<GS
>scf82887994<GS>4ld
```

I need the **18vlelme** removed from string. any ideas

Comment: Use this twice: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my other answer is not visible and since I know this answers your question, I will post it again.

I have done this a plethora of times at work, I configure barcode scanners for a living and if they remove my answer again, then I'll give up.

Step-by-step:

- Launch 123Scan².
- Select *Create a new configuration file*
- Select either of the options in this screen, it does not really matter whether your scanner is connected via USB or not.
- Select your model.
- Select *Modify data* in the left column.
- Select *Program complex data modifications*...
- *Advanced Data Formatting*.
- Create a new rule.
- Add action
- *Move to all patterns and replace*.
- Here you'll need to fill in the string you want to replace, in this case **18vlelme** and the data you want to replace it with. In this case nothing.
- Save it and add another.
- Select *Skip to start*.
- Save it and add another.
- Send all that remains.
- Save.

Now you want to send this configuration to the scanner, you can either load it via USB or you can create the configuration barcode and scan it.

After your scanner is configured, test it in notepad or using the *Data view* option of 123Scan².

One additional note, I would avoid asking these questions at SO and rather ask them here, [Zebra Technologies' Launchpad Developper Community](https://developer.zebra.com/welcome). Or their [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxLtlkUb0Lanig4YyDcP2fQ) where they have a few tutorials. This is a better resource for Symbol/Motorola/Zebra scanners related questions.